# where I host apps developed using tornado webserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webserver, hosting, tornado

Is It there any hosting service for hosting simple apps developed using tornado.(Like we hosting in Google App Engine). Is it possible to host on Google App Engine?.The Apps is just like some student datas(adding,removing,searching etc).I'm devoloped using python.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to host Tornado apps on App Engine; however, there are a couple caveats you need to keep in mind:

- App Engine is deploying everything through WSGI, which means that you can't take the advantage of Tornado's async features, providing that WSGI is asynchronous by design. If you can live with that, you need to wrap your app with `WSGIAdapter`:

  ```
  app = tornado.web.Application(url_list, **server_settings)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      # start the server if run directly
      import tornado.httpserver
      http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
      http_server.listen(8080, address='localhost')
      tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  else:
      # wrap as WSGI
      import tornado.wsgi
      app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app)
  ```
- App Engine requires all the app-specific libraries to be vendored within your source, so you can't use `virtualenvs` nor install libraries via `pip`, and all your modules **must** be pure Python. The best approach is to have a special directory, not tracked by your source control, and to install everything there locally with `pip install -U -t lib/ -r requirements.txt` (assuming the directory is called `lib`. Of course, you need to make your code aware of this directory by adding this somewhere in your app's configuration:

  ```
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com) can be good option for deploying your Tornado powered app.

This might be [helpful](http://log.liminastudio.com/programming/how-i-got-a-tornado-app-running-on-heroku-in-10-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

At heroku the WebSockets protocol is not yet supported on the Cedar stack.